# C# : Add xs:schema to creating file XML

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, export, schema

I have a datatable and I wanna export it to XML file. In my XML file, I want it have schema, as this format :

```
-<NewDataSet>
-<xs:schema xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" id="NewDataSet">
    -<xs:element msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msdata:IsDataSet="true" name="NewDataSet">
        -<xs:complexType>
            -<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                -<xs:element name="Table1">
                    -<xs:complexType>
                        -<xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="MA_NVGCS" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="MA_KHANG" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="MA_DDO" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="MA_DVIQLY" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
-<Table1>
    <MA_NVGCS/>
    <MA_KHANG>PC06LL0192456</MA_KHANG>
    <MA_DDO>PC06LL0192456001</MA_DDO>
    <MA_DVIQLY>PC06LL</MA_DVIQLY>
</Table1>
```

I'm using code :

```
ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\text.xml");
```

But it just export to format :

```
-<NewDataSet>
-<Table>
    <STATUS>Online</STATUS>
    <MESH>false</MESH>
    <NGAYGIO>2015-10-05T14:00:27+07:00</NGAYGIO>
    <MA_DVIQLY>DSP</MA_DVIQLY>
</Table>
```

How can I export my XML with xs:schema
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

I add  XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema to my code ( `ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(@"C:\Temp\text.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);` ) and the problem is solved. Thank to read my stupid question :D